# Why can I delete a folder, but not a locked pdf inside it?

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

Just came across this after reading a READ_ME pdf for an application. Accidentially moved it to bin, but it was password locked, and opening it displays locked in the preview app. But I can move the entire folder its stored in to the bin just fine.

Is there a reason I can't delete it, but I can delete the folder, and by extension, everything inside it, including the pdf?

Comment: “Moving to the bin” (Trash) is very different from actually deleting the file. The first moves the folder and contents to the `~/.Trash` folder and isn’t deleted until you empty the bin.  Deleting a file actually deletes it.  Can you share how you’re attempting to delete the file?  Is it a command or a Finder action?

Comment: It sounds like the PDF file itself has password protection, to prevent you reading it without the password. This is a feature of PDF, not of macOS, and is different to file permissions.

Comment: A password protected PDF cannot prevent it from being deleted.

Comment: @benwiggy no the pdf just had a lock on it to prevent me from editing it. Ignore my post I misread the window, I wasn't aware if I try and move a file to the bin from the applications folder it requires the admin password to do so. I thought it was asking for a password for the file

Comment: @Allan yes I made a mistake reading the window that came up. I thought it was asking for the pdf password, as it is locked to prevent editing. I didn't know that moving a file to the bin required the admin password if you are in the applications folder.